# strange convergence in norm

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I find it a bit strange that if $x_n \to x$ in Banach space $X$, then $|x_n|_X \to |x|_X$ by inverse triangle inequality... Surely that can't be right.

Am I correct in this? Does this have a name? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just the fact that the norm is a continuous function on a normed linear space.

Comment: Some people think it's necessary to prove that it's continuous under the typical metric space definitions.  In this case, you can show that:

Assume $||x_n - a|| \rightarrow 0$
Then $||x_n|| - ||a|| \leq ||x_n - a||$ and also $||a|| - ||x_n|| \leq ||x_n - a||$ and so $| ||x_n|| - ||a|| | \rightarrow 0$

Comment: And that is the correct proof.